Adding <b> tags around the bold text in a paragraph in a google document
I created this in purpose to convert an article to html format (you may already saw it from the way I tried putting headings inside  tags. etc).  However I'm having a trouble finding and handling bold text in the Doc. I have tried several ways and also asked for AI help.
function myFunction() {
  var outputHTML = DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KZcWSbrPg/edit?usp=sharing");
  var body2 = outputHTML.getBody();
  body2.clear(); //here is the cleared HTML output body
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var elements = body.getNumChildren(); //number of lines


  for (var i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    var line = body.getChild(i); //selects each line
    var type = line.getType().toString(); //type of the line
    
    if (type === "PARAGRAPH") {
      var paragraph = line.asParagraph();
      if (paragraph.getHeading() === DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL) {
        body2.appendParagraph("<p>" + paragraph.getText() + "<p>");

      } else if (paragraph.getHeading() === DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1) {
        body2.appendParagraph("<h1>" + paragraph.getText() + "</h1>");

      } else if (paragraph.getHeading() === DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2) {
        body2.appendParagraph("<h2>" + paragraph.getText() + "</h2>");

      } else{
        console.log("unknown");
      }
    } else {
      console.log(type);
    }
  }
}

I want to add  opening tag and closing tag around the bold texts in paragraphs. While the code reads the document line by line.

Google Docs is not html.  If you wish to bold  something create a style object and add attributes to it with DocumentApp.Attributes.

Here's an example from the documentation:
// Define a style with yellow background.
var highlightStyle = {};
highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#FFFF00';
highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

// Insert "Hello", highlighted.
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().editAsText()
  .insertText(0, 'Hello\n')
  .setAttributes(0, 4, highlightStyle);


DocumentApp.Attributes


No actually, What is want is to identify bold text/words within the paragraph. Not to check the whole paragraph is bold or not.

I could use a little more clarity in your question. But maybe that's just my problem.
